# How to store and populate data into dataGrid or table using reactJs and reactHooks?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

Am trying to get the user input data from the form and show it in the table/Datagrid below. But I am not getting the proper output.

Please see the process flow below

when the user submits the form and clicks the send now button, the **{handlSubmit}** function triggers and stores the value in **useState hooks(values).** Then am trying to retrieve the same value and populate it into the Datagrid below.

Please see the full source code on the sandbox link provided at the bottom.
Any help or suggestions are really appreciated and thanks in advance.

Please see the image below for the reference and output am getting at current stage.

**Note: the rows props in the Datagrid component only accept the array type.**

[image]

**Source Code:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import { Box, Button, Divider, Paper, Stack, TextField } from "@mui/material";

const Send = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    addressTo: "",
    amount: "",
    message: ""
  });

  const [storeData, setStoreData] = useState([]);
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setValues((values) => ({
      ...values,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log(values);
    setStoreData(Object.values(values));
  };

  const columns = [
    { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 70, align: "left", flex: 4 },
    {
      field: "AddressTo",
      headerName: "Address To",
      width: 130,
      align: "left",
      flex: 4
    },
    {
      field: "Amount",
      headerName: "Amount (in Eth)",
      width: 130,
      align: "left",
      flex: 4
    },
    {
      field: "Message",
      headerName: "Message",
      type: "text",
      width: 90,
      align: "left",
      flex: 4
    }
  ];

  const newId = new Date();
  const rows = storeData?.map((row) => ({
    id: newId.toISOString(),
    Amount: `${row.amount}`,
    AddressTo: `${row.addressTo}`,
    Message: `${row.message}`
  }));
  return (
    <>
      <Box className="frominputs">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <TextField
            name="addressTo"
            value={values.addressTo}
            onChange={handleChange}
            required
            fullWidth
            margin="dense"
            id="outlined-addressTo-input"
            placeholder="Address To"
            type="text"
          />
          <TextField
            name="amount"
            value={values.amount}
            onChange={handleChange}
            required
            fullWidth
            margin="dense"
            id="outlined-amount-input"
            placeholder="Amount in Eth"
            type="number"
          />
          <TextField
            name="message"
            value={values.message}
            onChange={handleChange}
            required
            fullWidth
            margin="dense"
            id="outlined-message-input"
            placeholder="Message"
            type="text"
          />

          <Divider
            sx={{
              background: "white",
              opacity: "0.7",
              marginTop: "5%",
              marginBottom: "5%"
            }}
          />
          <Button
            color="inherit"
            sx={{ border: "1px solid white", width: "100%", height: "45px" }}
            type="submit"
          >
            Send Now
          </Button>
        </form>
      </Box>

      <Box className="datatable" sx={{ height: 363 }}>
        <DataGrid
          rows={rows}
          columns={columns}
          pageSize={5}
          rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
          disableSelectionOnClick={true}
          sx={{ m: 2, width: "100%" }}
        />
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};

export default Send;
```

[Click to see demo and source code](https://codesandbox.io/s/sencrypapp-oiebuh?file=/src/Send.jsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the code there are multiple of errors, I fixed them all in this fork: https://codesandbox.io/s/sencrypapp-forked-kon8qh?file=/src/Send.jsx

Most are related to typization problems so maybe TS will be a good tool for you.
The IDs you were giving were the same ID for all items, I changed the IDs to numbers so it works, if you want date IDs you should add that to the data in the handleSubmit method.

Comment: Thanks, it did work as expected, and thanks a million for the ID part. But just a quick question if you do not mind, what exactly went wrong and how did resolve it sir?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to map over the list but aren't setting `values` to a list in `StoreData` hook. The `handleSubmit` function below should fix it

```
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log(values);
    setStoreData([...storeData, values]);
  };
```